# Spectron and electron without exe files

Tags: javascript, electron, spectron

I m trying to build an application using Electron.

I need to make some unit test based on the electron env and using electron packages.

This way, I m using spectron to simulate my application.

On the documentation, it's written that I have to put in 'path' property the path where my executable file is. I don't have executable for now, I m in development mode.

Here's what I've tried based on another question :

```
beforeEach(() => {
    app = new Application({
        path: 'node_modules/.bin/electron'
    });
    app.start().then(res => console.log(res), err => console.log(err));

});
```

Nothing appears on the prompt and the following test is failing telling that I can't get getWindowCount on an undefined object (clearly, the app isn't instantiated) :

```
 it('should call currentWindow', (done) => {
            app.client.getWindowCount().then((count) => {
                expect(count).to.equals(1);
                done();
            });
        });
```

Does anybody knows what should I put in this path to make my test env work ?

PS : I m using mocha chai and sinon.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `return app.start...;` in `beforeEach`.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?  I have similar thing with Ember-electron and spectron

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At first I was creating an executable for the purpose of testing, but that's actually not necessary.

You can see that Spectron has an [example test](https://github.com/electron/spectron/blob/master/test/example-test.js) and a [global setup](https://github.com/electron/spectron/blob/master/test/global-setup.js).

The example passes an option called [args](https://github.com/electron/spectron/blob/master/test/example-test.js#L17), and that’s exactly what you are missing. This is what I am doing:

```
  var appPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../'); //require the whole thing
  var electronPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules/.bin/electron');

  beforeEach(function() {
    myApp = new Application({
      path: electronPath,
      args: [appPath], // pass args along with path
    });

   return myApp.start().then(function() {
     assert.equal(myApp.isRunning(), true);
     chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = myApp.transferPromiseness;
     return myApp;
   });
 });
```

My test sits in ./tests/app-test.js. The above works for me.

Comment: Hi, I am trying the same thing somehow it is not working could you please check this https://discuss.atom.io/t/spectron-not-triggering-app/48123

Comment: Some one from electron-slack helped me to fix that issue.any way thanks for taking a look

Answer (score 2):

You can also provides "electron" to the variables path if you use electron-prebuilt as mentioned in the [doc](https://github.com/electron/spectron) :

> path - Required. String path to the Electron application executable to
>   launch. Note: If you want to invoke electron directly with your app's
>   main script then you should specify path as electron via
>   electron-prebuilt and specify your app's main script path as the first
>   argument in the args array.

I think it looks like this :

```
import electron from 'electron'
import { Application } from 'spectron'

describe('application launch', function () {
  this.timeout(10000)

  beforeEach(function () {
    this.app = new Application({
      path: electron,
      args: ['app']
    })
    return this.app.start()
  })
...
}
```